# I wrote the angular and asp.net core codes in different directives. Is this ok for me when im deploy app?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, api, asp.net-core

this is my main folder structure

-- MainApp

--- (1.)Server

----- Api

--- (2.)Client

----- Angular

Comment: Probably. You just need to configure the web server correctly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not really be a problem if you configure it correctly afaik.